# Compare two objects that have boolean, string and object as value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two objects.

one is defaultValue object that not gonna be changed and the another is comparedValue that can be changed.

```
const defaultValues = {
  adminProfile: "Option 1",
  channel: {id: 0, name: ''},
  datetime: moment().format("yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssz"),
  memo: '',
  phoneNumber: 'none',
  register: 'yes',
  source: {id: 0, name: ''},
  starred: false,
  studio: 'common',
  subject: {id: 0, name: ''},
}

const comparedValues = {
  adminProfile: "Option 1",
  channel: {id: 0, name: ''},
  datetime: moment().format("yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssz"),
  memo: '',
  phoneNumber: 'none',
  register: 'yes',
  source: {id: 0, name: ''},
  starred: false,
  studio: 'common',
  subject: {id: 0, name: ''},
}
```

If one of value of property is different than another, function returns false.

Here is the code that I wrote

```
const validation = (comparedValues) => {

  return  Object.keys(defaultValues).some(value => {
    if (comparedValues.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
      if (typeof comparedValues[value] === 'object') {
        comparedValues[value].id === defaultValues[value].id
      }
       comparedValues[value] === defaultValues[value]
    }
  })
};
```

However this function always return true, how to make function compares two objects and other values one by one and returns false when it catches difference?

Comment: Your missing `return`

Comment: ...in the callback of `.some()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

The first one is that you do not return `true` or `false` from the callback passed to `.some()`.

The second one is that you use `.some()` which returns `true` if *at least one* item in the array suits the condition. However, you need to check *all* of them to be equal. It means you need to use `.every()` instead of `some()`.

To fix everything, add the `return` statement into callback and use `every()`:

```
const validation = (comparedValues) => {

  return  Object.keys(defaultValues).every(value => {
    if (comparedValues.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
      if (typeof comparedValues[value] === 'object') {
        return comparedValues[value].id === defaultValues[value].id
      }
       return comparedValues[value] === defaultValues[value]
    }
  })
};
```

Now `validation` function will return `true` if ALL default values are equal to compared values.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to compare two objects :D

```
const compare = (objectA, objectB) => {
  return JSON.stringify(objectA) === JSON.stringify(objectB);
}
```